# I would like to change my email address in my personal settings in Playground

Tags: trailhead

[image]

Hello, my name is Ta-kun.

I would like to ask you about creating a Playground.
I created a Playground from Trailhead and logged in for the first time.
When I logged in for the first time, an unfamiliar email address was set in the "Personal Information" email address in the image I pasted.

I deleted and saved the "Email" email address, but it never changed.

What steps should I take in such a case?

If possible, the email address set in the trailhead profile should have been set when the playground was created.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please note that we are not an official part of Salesforce. While there are some Salesforce employees among us, >= 99% of the people here are users like yourself. If you need official support, then https://trailhead.salesforce.com/help is going to be a better resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The e-mail address of your Trailhead Playground user is changed like the email of your user on any other org. (In fact Trailhead Playgrounds are largely normal Salesforce orgs.)

- Edit and save your email address. (At this point you should see an informational message like "To ensure system security, you must verify the change to your outgoing email address...")
- Check the email inbox of the email address that you entered as your new email. Click on the confirmation link in your email.

> If possible, the email address set in the trailhead profile should have been set when the playground was created.

If this is not the case, ask in the [Trailhead group](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F9300000009NekCAE).

Comment: I had a feeling that this (get an email giving you a link to verify the new email address) was the case, but didn't know for certain.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
Resolved.

After changing my email address, I received a notification of the change to my changed email address.

We have since confirmed that the email address has been changed.